# Prove the Linear Algebra about Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, formal-proofs

I have to do a proof about a linear algebra matrix but I'm stuck on how to go about doing the proof.

Here's the proof:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix, and $λ$ an eigenvalue of $A$.
Then $λ+µ$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $M=A+µI$, where $I$ is the $n \times n$ matrix.

How do I go about doing this proof?

I can see that if we do the $det(A-λI)$ to find the eigenvalues we can get the eigenvalue of the matrix $M$ to be $λ+µ$, but how do I prove this, and I also don't really understand what I'm trying to prove in the above statement.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Consider the eigenvector $v$ then

$$Mv=(A+µI)v=Av+µv=(λ+µ)v$$

Comment: Ok thank you, wouldn't that equal $(A+µ)v$? or are you replacing A with λ?

Comment: @TheStatistician Note that $Av=λv$ by definition.

Comment: @TheStatistician Observe that $\;Av+\mu v=(A+\mu I)v\; ...$

Comment: @gimusi thank you, i didn't remember that but thank you.
What do I need to prove next after doing that part as I don't actually understand what I trying to prove in this?

Comment: @TheStatistician After this you are done. Recall that by definition we said that $λ$ is an  eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector v when the following holds $Av=λv$. From here we have shown that $Mv=(A+µI)v=Av+µv=(λ+µ)v$ then $(λ+µ)$ is eigenvalue for M with eigenvector v.

Comment: @TheStatistician To recall and for review https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}\lambda+\mu\text{ is an eigenvalue of }A+\mu\operatorname{Id}&\iff\det\bigl(A+\mu\operatorname{Id}-(\lambda+\mu)\operatorname{Id}\bigr)=0\\&\iff\det(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id})=0,\end{align}which is true, since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Thank you this is all helping so much.
I know that's part of the proof and i understand what you're talking about.  Would you be able to help me understand what I need to be proving next after doing that part?

Comment: @TheStatistician That's the whole proof, not just part of it.

Comment: Oh okay thank you, i thought that was just part of it, but thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Let A be an n×n matrix, and λ an eigenvalue of A. Then λ+µ is an eigenvalue of the matrix M=A+µI, where I is the n×n matrix.

$$AV=\lambda V for V\ne 0 $$

$$ (A+\mu I-(\lambda +\mu))V= AV+ \mu V-\lambda V-\mu V =AV-\lambda V=0$$

That is $ \lambda +\mu$ is an eigenvalue for   A+\mu I$